# git clean deleted everything on laptop

Tags: git

I changed my local pathway for a git repo I had and kept on getting untracked files in my terminal. So I unfortunately proceeded to use git clean -d -f, and apprently did it in a higher directory which deleted a ton of files, is there any way I could retrieve them:

```
hamed [] :> git status
On branch master

Initial commit

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   .CFUserTextEncoding
    new file:   DBC/phase-0-unit-1
    new file:   DBC/salehrastani.github.io

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   DBC/phase-0-unit-1 (new commits)
    modified:   DBC/salehrastani.github.io (new commits)

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    .config/
    .cups/
    .dvdcss/
    .gem/
    .npm/
    .rbenv/
    .ssh/
    .subversion/
    Desktop/
    Documents/
    Downloads/
    Library/
    Movies/
    Music/
    Pictures/
    ...
```

Thank you...

Comment: Don't download books illegally :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. Not with Git.

You've initialized a Git repository right in your home directory and then told Git to remove all untracked files there. If that command was called not in a Git repository, it would refuse to proceed, but that was not the case.

So, it's time to see if you have a backup.

Comment: A hard lesson learned!